# Composition of two cube rotation symmetries, that lie along perpendicular axis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles, cayley-table

Want to find the orbits of the group of $24$ rotations of the
[cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuMaZ.jpg).

The rotations about the axis, formed by the midpoints of the anti-podal faces parallel to the $x-z$ plane have the $3$ non-trivial symmetries as:

1. $\alpha=(1234)(5678),$
2. $\alpha^2=(13)(24)(57)(68),$
3. $\alpha^3=(1432)(5876),$

And, the symmetries along the axis, formed by the midpoints of the anti-podal faces parallel to the $x-y$ plane have the $3$ non-trivial symmetries as:

4: $\alpha'=(3762)(4851),$ 
5: $\alpha'^2= (36)(27)(81)(45),$ 
6: $\alpha'^3= (3267)(4158),$

If want to compute $\alpha\alpha'=(1234)(5678)(3267)(4851),$ then have two doubts.

1. Is composition of symmetries along perpendicular axis, meaningful in practice?
2. Get two maps for many elements. Say, for the element $2:$
   $2\rightarrow 7, $ and $2\rightarrow 3;$ as shown below in (f), (n) respectively:

Processing permutations from right to left, with individual map being processed from right to left:

First permutation from the right:

(a). $4\rightarrow 8, 8\rightarrow 5 : 4\rightarrow 5,$
(b). $8\rightarrow 5, 5\rightarrow 6: 8\rightarrow 6,$
(c). $5\rightarrow 1, 1\rightarrow 2: 5\rightarrow 2,$
(d). $1\rightarrow 4, 4\rightarrow 1: 1\rightarrow 1,$

---

Second permutation from the right:

(e). $3\rightarrow 2, 2\rightarrow 3: 3\rightarrow 3,$
(f). $2\rightarrow 6, 6\rightarrow 7: 2\rightarrow 7,$
(g). $6\rightarrow 7, 7\rightarrow 8: 6\rightarrow 8,$
(h). $7\rightarrow 3, 3\rightarrow 4: 7\rightarrow 4.$

---

Third permutation from the right:

(i) $5\rightarrow 6,$ get second map for the vertex $5,$ 
(j) $6\rightarrow 7,$ get second map for the vertex $6,$ 
(k) $7\rightarrow 8,$ get second map for the vertex $7,$ 
(l) $8\rightarrow 5.$

---

Fourth permutation from the right:

(m) $1\rightarrow 2,$ get second map for the vertex $1,$ 
(n) $2\rightarrow 3,$ get second map for the vertex $2,$ 
(o) $3\rightarrow 4,$ get second map for the vertex $3,$ 
(p) $4\rightarrow 1,$ get second map for the vertex $4.$

What should be the final map is unclear.

It cannot be
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
2&3&4&1&6&7&8&5
\end{pmatrix} $= (1234)(5678)?$

as that is illogical, as the second rotation made no effect.

Hence, should such (of the symmetries along the perpendicular axis) composition be ignored simply?

If so, how to fill the corresponding entries in the group table?

**Edit :** The permutations are a bijective map. Hence, the composition of permutations is to be taken for any element in any permutation, once only.

The main error above is that the last two permutations, i.e.$(1234)(5678)$ are taken again. Also, there is error in taking one permutation of $\alpha'^3$ instead of $\alpha.$

The same is being pointed by the first comment of @JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: You miscopied one of the cycles. The product $$\alpha\alpha'=(1234)(5678)(3762)(4851)=(1)(245)(386)(7)$$ is a 120 degree rotation about the diagonal connecting vertices 1 and 7.

Comment: I was taught that a symbol like $(4851)$ is a *cycle*, which is a special kind of permutation. You don't do four separate maps starting at each cycle, you do one map that processes each element through all four cycles. So for element $1$, apply $(4851)$, so $1\to4,$ then apply $(3762)$, but $4$ is not in that cycle so there is no change, then apply $(5678)$ but again there is no change, then apply $(1234)$, so $4\to1.$ End result: $1\to4\to1,$ that is, $1\to1.$ That is the entire story of what $1$ is mapped to; there is no second map.

Comment: You may also need to do compositions of cycles until it becomes second nature. Here (from right to left) in the product of four 4-cycles: $1\mapsto 4\mapsto 4\mapsto4\mapsto 1$ so $(1)$ is a cycle by itself. Then $2\mapsto2\mapsto 3\mapsto 3\mapsto 4$,
$4\mapsto 8\mapsto 8\mapsto 5\mapsto 5$ and $5\mapsto 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 1\mapsto 2$, and we have completed a 3-cycle $(245)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sir, thanks a lot. Is it possible to interpret intuitively the $90^o$ counter-clockwise rotation about the axis, through the anti-podal faces parallel to the $x-y$ plane, followed by a similar rotation about the axis parallel to the $x-z$ plane; as a rotation about the pair $1-7$ of anti-podal vertices.

Comment: May be you need to do this with a physical cube? The rotation $\alpha'$ moves the corner 1 to corner 4. Then the rotation $\alpha$ moves it back from corner 4 to corner 1, so *in the composition* corner 1 stays where it is. Because rotations preserve distances, the opposite corner 7 must also stay where it is (it is the only corner of the cube at distance $\sqrt3$ from corner 1, so it cannot go anywhere else). The rotations are linear transformations so the entire 3D-diagonal 17 must be fixed, and therefore the composition is a rotation about that axis.